# Macro gets partial response using serverxmlhttp requests

Tags: vba, web-scraping, xmlhttprequest, serverxmlhttp

I'm trying to extract `street address` along with the `builder name` from a [webpage](https://www.redfin.com/TX/Austin/604-Amesbury-Ln-78752/unit-2/home/171045975). When I use `xmlhttp60` requests I get those fields accordingly. However, when I go for `serverxmlhttp60` requests I get partial response most of the times and as a result the script only prints the `street adddress`. I used [json converter](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON) to parse `builder name` out of json content from that site.

Here is the proof of concept:

```
Sub GrabPropertyInfo()
    Const siteLink$ = "https://www.redfin.com/TX/Austin/604-Amesbury-Ln-78752/unit-2/home/171045975"

    Dim oPost As Object, oData As Object, Html As HTMLDocument
    Dim jsonObject As Object, jsonStr As Object, propertyMainRaw$
    Dim itemStr As Variant, sResp As String, oElem As Object
    Dim propertyContainer As Object, propertyMain As Object
    
    Set Html = New HTMLDocument
    
'    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
'        .Open "GET", siteLink, False
'        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36"
'        .send
'        sResp = .responseText
'        Html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
'    End With
    
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
        .Open "GET", siteLink, True
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36"
        .send
        While .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        sResp = .responseText
        Html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

    Debug.Print "Street address: " & Html.querySelector("h1.homeAddress > .street-address").innerText
    
    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .Global = True
        .Pattern = "reactServerState\.InitialContext = (.*);"
        .MultiLine = True
        Set jsonStr = .Execute(sResp)
    End With
    

    itemStr = jsonStr(0).submatches(0)
    Set jsonObject = JsonConverter.ParseJson(itemStr)
    Set propertyMain = jsonObject("ReactServerAgent.cache")("dataCache")("/stingray/api/home/details/mainHouseInfoPanelInfo")("res")
    propertyMainRaw = Replace(propertyMain("text"), "{}&&", "")

    On Error Resume Next
    Set propertyContainer = JsonConverter.ParseJson(propertyMainRaw)("payload")("mainHouseInfo")("amenitiesInfo")("superGroups")
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not propertyContainer Is Nothing Then
        For Each oElem In propertyContainer
            For Each oPost In oElem("amenityGroups")
                If InStr(oPost("groupTitle"), "Building Information") > 0 Then
                    For Each oData In oPost("amenityEntries")
                        If InStr(oData("amenityName"), "Builder Name") > 0 Then
                            Debug.Print "Builder Name: " & oData("amenityValues")(1)
                        End If
                    Next oData
                End If
            Next oPost
        Next oElem
    End If
End Sub
```

Using xmlhttp requests, I always get:

```
Street address: 604 Amesbury Ln #2,
Builder Name: Zach Savage
```

Using serverxmlhttp requests, I get the following result most of the time:

```
Street address: 604 Amesbury Ln #2,
```

> How can I get complete response using serverxmlhttp requests?

***EDIT:***

According to the answer and comments, it is clear that if I scrape `browserid` from that site using `xmlhttp` requests and use the value of that `browserid` as cookie while sending requests using `serverxmlhttp`, I'll get the desired results. However, The problem is the value of the `browserid` that I get using `xmlhttp` requests is `sz9u0xmCQKKV9Wu0jRa3Yg` whereas I can see this value `v-J5D2IUSyqXizI7MG67fQ` in page source. How can I get the latter value? This is how I parsed `browserid`.

```
Sub FetchBrowserId()
    Const siteLink$ = "https://www.redfin.com/TX/Austin/604-Amesbury-Ln-78752/unit-2/home/171045975"
 
    Dim Rxp As Object, browserId As Object, sRes$, cookie$
 
    Set Rxp = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
 
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", siteLink, False
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.61 Safari/537.36"
        .send
        sRes = .responseText
    End With
 
    With Rxp
        .Global = True
        .Pattern = "window.__rfBrowserId=""(.*?)"";"
        .MultiLine = True
        Set browserId = .Execute(sRes)
    End With
 
    cookie = browserId(0).submatches(0)
    Debug.Print cookie
End Sub
```

Comment: `xmlhttp60`? If you mean `xmlhttp`, it should return the same as `ServerXMLHTTP.6.0`, referencing 'Microsoft XML, v6.0', I think. Are you logged in when try the code?

Comment: I used exactly the code I pasted above @FaneDuru. As you can see I didn't use credentials within the script, so I didn't log in. I didn't manually log in either. However, they both (`xmlhttp` and `ServerXMLHTTP`) should return the same response but in reality it is not. Here you can see an exception. I would like to know how I can fix that. Thanks.

Comment: Currently the script is using `ServerXMLHTTP` requests. You can use `XMLHTTP60` requests by uncommenting the relevant portion above.

Comment: The above code returns **exactly the same**, when I tested it... Of course, uncommenting the commented part and jumping over the `ServerXMLHTTP`. I was asking about logging in because I didn't know if the site expose something more  in case of being logged in. `XMLHTTP` does not care about cookies and `ServerXMLHTTP` does, but testing as I tried explaining, both of them return `"Street address: 604 Amesbury Ln #2,"`...

Comment: Why do you need `browserid` from page source? And how does it related to cookies?

Comment: Because when you use this line `.setRequestHeader "Cookie", "RF_BROWSER_ID=v-J5D2IUSyqXizI7MG67fQ;"` in the first script, you should get complete results. [This is](https://pastebin.com/TeYScYC9) how the script looks when that cookie is implemented.

Comment: You should extract cookies from response `set-cookie` headers rather than from page source. To reduce response time you may use HEAD method instead of GET.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the actual question I guess is why there are different responses returned by `MSXML2.XMLHTTP` and `MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP` requests made to the same URL.

`MSXML2.XMLHTTP` uses WinINet stack and `MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP` uses WinHTTP stack. Check [WinINet vs. WinHTTP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/wininet/wininet-vs-winhttp) article for more details.

WinINet provide full processing of cookies (BTW IE also rely on it). So the first reason you have different responses is that cookies sent to server may affect flow. It can be easily compared with any service like e. g. [Webhook.site](https://webhook.site/). When you make second request with `MSXML2.XMLHTTP` the webservice logs the cookies which have been accepted from first response.

Also take in account SSL conditions. Make requests to [How's My SSL?](https://www.howsmyssl.com/a/check) by `MSXML2.XMLHTTP` and `MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP`, and follow the link in browser (i. e. Chrome) and compare results.

Comment: Thanks for your elaborative answer. After complying with the suggestion made by @FaneDuru, I could figure out that I get complete response when I use this cookie `.setRequestHeader "Cookie", "RF_BROWSER_ID=v-J5D2IUSyqXizI7MG67fQ;"`. Now, my question is, can I not automate this portion `v-J5D2IUSyqXizI7MG67fQ` other than hardcoding the value?

Comment: If cookies matters and using `MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP` then you have to receive, store and send cookies. Hardcoded cookie sooner or later appear to be rejected by server.

Comment: @robots.txt Could you please update your question with new section including the code you pasted on pastebin and issue description, thus to keep the discussion consistent and in one place.

Comment: I've edited the question to include further attempt.